# "File" class object size?

Tags: java, spring, file

I want to know whether the object of a `File` class loads the entire file on the main memory. I thought of using the 2 files, one big and one small to make the objects of file class and then comparing the size of these two objects. But apparently, there is no straightforward way to determine the size of the objects in `Java`.

Comment: `the object of a File class loads the entire file on the main memory` - no, it even does not load file at all, you can have object for non-existent file

Comment: [File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) - `An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames.`

Comment: Are you looking for `File.length()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`File` object is just a plain object with a reference to a file path. The referenced file may or may not actually exist in the file system. File object does not hold content of the file.

When you read a file using `InputStream` (e.g. `FileInputStream`)  or `Reader` (e.g. `FileReader`) in conjunction with a Buffer (e.g. `BufferedReader`), you start reading the actual file content. Now, it is up to you whether you want to keep the whole file content data in the memory or process chunk by chunk and discard it. So, whether or not full file content is loaded into memory depends on your application.

In order to know the file size upfront in bytes, you may do: `file.length()`

In order to know the file content size after reading, while reading the file store content into `byte array` (`byte[]`) and measure the length of the array using `mybytes.length`.

#### Update

You have mentioned in the comment that you want to find out the size of `File` object. `File` object is just another usual object. Still, if you want to measure the size use `java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation#getObjectSize()`

Please refer to this article [How to use the Java Instrumentation API](https://openapex.org/spaces/software/how-to-use-the-java-instrumentation-api-to-determine-object-size/) to understand how to determine object size using `java.lang.instrument` classes.

Comment: @Andreas rephrased the sentence.

Comment: Does the file.length() give the size of file object or the size of the file whose meta data it represents?

Comment: Just to make sure it is impossible that my whole file gets loaded on the RAM when  I am only using the File class's object in my program, right?

Comment: @sv2311 `file.length()` returns the size of the referenced file path if it exists in the file system otherwise, returns 0. Yes, unless you read the file, merely creating a File object does not load any content into memory.

Comment: Referenced file path is what the object of File class represents, right?

Comment: Actually, I wanted to know is there any way to know the size of the object? That's what I intended to ask in the original question. I wanted to know the size of the File object and not the file itself.

Comment: What you will do with File object size? File object is just another usual object. Still if you want to measure use `java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation#getObjectSize()`

Comment: @sv2311 Please refer to this article [How to use the Java Instrumentation API to determine object size](https://openapex.org/spaces/software/how-to-use-the-java-instrumentation-api-to-determine-object-size/) to understand how to determine object size using `java.lang.instrument` classes.

Comment: Added a section at the end of the answer on determining object size. Please check.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to compare the size of the file's content in memory, you need to read from the file object. If you store the data in a byte array, you can measure the length of the byte array.

Comment: Untrue. `File.length()` gives you the file size without any reading at all.

Comment: @user207421 Please read my statement more carefully. It refers explicitly to the file's content in memory. You're confusing this with the size of the file on the file system. Anyway, File.length() requires reading from the disk. How do you think the file's size is determined without interacting with the file system?

Comment: The OP only has a `File` object, and a `File` object does not have any 'content in memory' other than the path. He doesn't need to read from the to get it all into memory only so he can measure what's in memory, when he can just look up the directory. Your answer and comment don't make sense.

Comment: @user207421, please don't guess what is in memory. It is very bad engineering. Also please don't guess the OP's intent. That's what the discussion is meant to communicate.